# ngClass in angular understanding syntax

Tags: angular, ng-class

I am going through some code and I found a syntax like this :

```
<div class="test" [ngClass]="{'active': isOverlay, 'on-page': onPage, 'spinner': showLoader, 'scroll': alphabetScroll}">
```

I am trying to understand what does this but I am not able to. What is all with the ngClass.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if `isOverlay == true` then apply class `active`
if `onPage == true` then apply class `on-page` and so on....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be understood like:

```
<tagname [ngClass]="{'class-name': flagVariable}"></tagname>
```

Where:

**tagname:** Is the HTML element.

**ngClass:** Is a directive that adds and removes CSS classes on an HTML element.

**class-name:** Is the name of the class which you want to apply on the element.

**flagVariable:** Is the variable of type boolean that actually exists in ts file that decides that the class should be applied or not on the element. If the value of the `flagVariable` is true class will be applied otherwise not.

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description).

Answer (score 1):

That means **if `isOverlay` returns true** a class **`active`** will be **added to that div element** and so on. So `ngClass` is a built-in angular directive **to add and remove classes based on boolean attributes**.

Answer (score 0):

Simply [ngClass] define Adds and removes CSS classes on an HTML element.

To further information checkout https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-Class to give these properties the you element or componen

Answer (score 0):

`ngClass` is directive used for adding and removing css class from html element. More information checkout the official [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).